# Unable to load multiple class files in java

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, classpath, teradata

I have been trying to run the following code. When I try to run it, either the main class won't load or the other jar files won't

This is my code

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver;

public class TeradataSample
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        String connurl="jdbc:teradata://path";

        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner 

        System.out.println("Enter username");
        String userName = myObj.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter password");
        String psswd = myObj.nextLine();

        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connurl, userName, psswd);

        System.out.println(" Connected to Teradata. \n");

        System.out.println("Enter your query");
        String query = myObj.nextLine();

        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("\n Statement object created. \n");

        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()) 
        {
            String col1=rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println("col1="+col1);
        }

        stmt.close();
        System.out.println("\n Statement object closed. \n");

        conn.close();
        System.out.println(" Connection to Teradata closed. \n");
    }
}
```

while compiling, I used

`javac TeradataSample.java`

I got the following error

```
error: package com.teradata.jdbc does not exist
import com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver;
                        ^
```

executing,
So I tried loading classpath of terajdbc4.jar which is actually in the same directory as the program Teradatasample.java .

```
javac -cp . TeradataSample.java
```

There was no error

For execution,
I tried this.

`java TeradataSample`

Running gives me the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class TeradataSample
```

So I thought of including the class path and tried this

`java -cp . TeradataSample`

now it gave me the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:teradata://path
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at TeradataSample.main(TeradataSample.java:38)
```

It is loading the main class but not the jar files.

Hence I tried this
`java -cp .;C:\Test\* TeradataSample`

well back to square one,I got the below error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class TeradataSample
```

I can't set classpath variable as I don't have admin rights.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: did you actually add them to your  classpath?

Comment: How about adding `-jar terajdbc4.jar` to your `javac` and `java` command.

Comment: Does your jar file contain the driver for the specific database you are using ?

Comment: @Stultuske I can't add them to classpath because I dont I have admin rights

Comment: well, that's why it doesn't work

Comment: @Stultuske  -cp option still works, I just need to figure out how both Main class and jar can be loaded

Comment: Even without admin rights you can issue `set CLASSPATH=` before you issue the `java` command. Note that you need to specify the actual jar file for the driver in CLASSPATH or -cp and not just the directory.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows, Linux, MacOS, something else? Only on Windows the separator is `;`, on other platforms it's `:`.

Comment: The statement `import com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver` is unnecessary in your code as you don't actually reference the `TeraDriver` class in your code. The driver will be loaded automatically if it is on the classpath. You only need to `import` things that you directly reference by name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to list the jar file in the argument for the `-cp` option like this:

```
java -cp .;terajdbc4.jar TeradataSample
```

Comment: when I give more than 1 argument to -cp it is not recognizing both the arguments.
I got Error: Could not find or load main class TeradataSample

Comment: On Windows, use a semicolon separator: `java -cp .;terajdbc4.jar TeradataSample`

On Linux, Mac, or others, use a colon separator: `java -cp .:terajdbc4.jar TeradataSample`